# Design UI Android (Element between CardViews)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

My question is more informative. I just want to know how to make such design. I found android application called "weather timeline" and inside of that application between CardViews (as I understand) they used this element which I pointed out in picture below. I think its just ImageView but how to set it as here. It will be interesting to know any idea about that! Thanks for attection!

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's just a layout trick. You'd implement the circle design in all cells, and just reveal it for the before/after cells to the injected cell.

Comment: Hello man! Thanks for reply. I am not exactly understand you. Is it possible to show my some examples or explain it more detaily.

Comment: I just posted u some explanation, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily do it in the following way. 
Let us assume that we are using a collection view where the card element is one type and the black gap with text in the middle is the other.
The cardView would look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/circle_radius_half_size"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/circle_radius_half_size">
    </CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_radius"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_radius"
        android:layout_align_parentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" 
        android:rotation="180"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_radius"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_radius"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where drawable circle looks something like this
[image: Circle]

and the layout for black grape with text in the middle looks something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_line"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin_left="@dimen/line_margin"
        android:background="@color/white" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin_left="@dimen/line_margin" >


        <!-- The Text View Layouts Here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where `line_margin` is `24dp + CircleHalfSize - LineWidthHalfSize`

Of course the `CircleHalfSize` and `LineWidthHalfSize` are in `DP`

Now it is just a question of arranging them properly via the adapter. Personally I would use the RecyclerView. Great Flexibility.

Also this way if you wanted the bubbles to be gone, all you have to do is set the bubble ImageView's visibility to `GONE` and that too you can do specifically either for the top or the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is interesting to me how you want to make that design with RecyclerView. You said it is more Flexibility.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes as far as collection views go I think recycler view is the way to go for android. It really is very efficient and highly flexible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this could be accomplished using **9-patched** images.

By determining the way to draw your patches and how to set them as a background for your layouts you'll get the same result.

## Quick illustrated demo

[image: Here is one of the 9 patched imaged that could have been used (the red line is separating the patches.]

[image: And here is another one]

By adjusting the two backgrounds exactly one above the other you'll get the UI you posted.

Hope it helps.

## Further reading

To see how to draw 9-patched images [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) is a documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a RelativeLayout.  Then you can align all your views however you want inside your main view.

Thus, you would layout Card1 at the top, then layout the bubble connector with your marginTop attribute (remember this is from the top of the container, not from the bottom of the card) to layout that view wherever you want.

Basically, you would use a single RelativeLayout, then align the various views within that container wherever you want in relation to each other (or really in relation to the the top of your main view).

Checkout this Pseudo-code:

```
<RelativeLayout >
    <CardView
        layout_height = "8dp"
        alignParentTop = "true"
    />

    <!-- Connector Image -->
    <ImageView 
        alignParentTop = "true"
        layoutMarginTop = "10dp" <!-- or whatever it takes to align properly with CardView -->
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```